# Convert first False value to True using categorical group with 70 unique values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert the first occurrence of False to True in a column in a Pandas Dataframe. The Column in question contains True, False and null values. My current code is:

`df.loc[df.groupby('categorical_col')[''].idxmin(), 'target_col'] = True`

However this gives me the following error:

`TypeError: reduction operation 'argmin' not allowed for this dtype`

How can I convert the first occurrence of False to True while incorporating the categorical group?

Edit sample data:

| categorical_col | target_col |
| --- | --- |
| A | TRUE |
| A | TRUE |
| A | TRUE |
| A | TRUE |
| A | FALSE |
| B | TRUE |
| B |  |
| B |  |
| B | TRUE |
| B | FALSE |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is column `target_col` is not boolean, but filled by strings:

```
print (df)
   categorical_col  target_col
0                1       False
1                1       False
2                2        True

print (df.target_col.dtypes)
object
```

For boolean compare by string `'True'`:

```
df['target_col'] = df['target_col'].eq('True')

df.loc[df.groupby('categorical_col')['target_col'].idxmin(), 'target_col'] = True
print (df)
   categorical_col  target_col
0                1        True
1                1       False
2                2        True
```